# Chaining unrelated inventions

Tags: patent-applications, continuation

I asked [this question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/10497/do-divisional-applications-have-the-same-detailed-description) and it seems there divisional applications can have the same detailed description.

I know that before the patent is issued, I can file another application claim priority date of the first application, e.g. continuation or divisional.

What I am trying to do is filing a application with multiple unrelated inventions (see the image below). I will pursue an invention but repeat the whole detailed description about multiple invention. While I pursue one invention, I will try to find commercial potential of other inventions. If another invention has commercial potential, I will file continuation application about it. It seems this will be perfectly legal.

As an independent inventor, I hope that strategy will reduce cost, as I only pursue just one invention instead of pursuing multiple ones at the same time. But in practice, they are unrelated inventions, so can I file continuation application like that?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A less strange way of doing this would be to put them all in one provisional application, and within a year filing a provisional describing and claiming invention 1. It would incorporate the whole provisional by reference. A continuation of that application could claim priority chained back to the provisional. I think it should work but if the inventions were completely unrelated I wouldn't recommend doing it.

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend it? Since it is legal it must be accepted. Or do you think my method is better for unrelated inventions?

Comment: Doing something extremely unusual that is untested in the courts in order to achieve a small cost savings is not very safe.